# Client getting wrong option from DHCP server

Tags: pxe-boot, tftp, dhcpd

I'm setting up a machine to load a Debian intallation with PXEBoot, following the guide on the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall). I have the boot image sitting on a server, `pxe.example.com`, at `/var/lib/tftpboot/debian-jessie/pxelinux.0`. I can download that file manually from any machine on my network when I use `tftp pxe.example.com`, but I'm still getting this error when I boot up the client machine:

```
PXE-T01: File not found
PXE-E3B: TFTP Error - File Not found
PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.
```

The problem is that even though I have this in my `/etc/dchpd.conf` on my DHCP server:

```
group {
    next-server pxe.example.com;
    option option-209 "/debian-jessie/pxelinux.cfg/default";
    filename "/debian-jessie/pxelinux.0";

    host theclient {
        hardware ethernet my:ma:ca:dd:re:ss;
        fixed-address theclient.example.com;
    }
}
```

and have run `/etc/rc.d/dhcpd restart` after every edit, and the client is getting an IP address from the server, it is still trying to download the wrong filename from `pxe`! The PXE server's `daemon.log` shows:

```
in.tftpd: RRQ from <client's ip> filename debian-bios/pxelinux.0
in.tftpd: sending NAK (1, File not found) to <client's ip>
```

I tried the obvious hack-around, to just change the name of `debian-jessie` to `debian-bios` but that still ends up failing because the directory structure doesn't match. What I cannot figure out is where it is getting the idea that the directory is called `debian-bios` in the first place! This is an update to an older system, but the word "bios" doesn't even appear anywhere in in my `dhcpd.conf`, so where could that filename be coming from?

Like I said, I restarted `dhcpd`, and I can see that it's giving an IP address to the client. The whole handshake is happening and working correctly, but the filename option it's getting is somehow wrong anyway.

I must be missing something. Does anyone know where else it might be retrieving that option, or any other reason why it's not doing what I expect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the word "bios" doesn't even appear anywhere in in my dhcpd.conf, so where could that filename be coming from?

It surely comes from a "second" PXE enabled DHCP server you have in your net...

or

/etc/dchpd.conf is not the conf file really driving your DHCP daemon.

In these cases a Wireshark traffic capture can really help a lot.

Comment: Huh. It turned out there were multiple `dhcpd` processes running on the server, other than the one run by rc.d. Didn't see that one coming!